# Can Chrome browser history be seen on work wifi, even if not re-loaded?

Tags: wifi, android, chrome

I use the work wifi daily but am always conscious of using work related sites.

However Android tends to keep most apps running in the browser so my windows(tabs) are never essentially closed down. If I take my phone to work and the tabs are still open on the phone from what I was browsing at home or on the train but are not re-loaded, will this show up on the works internet history?

I know that work wifi history sites are checked.

Comment: AFAIK, yes. Chrome (and many other mobile browser) tend to reload or at least reconnect to the websites when scripts resume and transfer tracking information back to other websites, including the one you are currently browsing on. Websites that are not reloaded (because they are kept in memory) and do not track you, will not show up, though.

Answer (score 2):

It will only show up in their history if the page loads something.

The problem is there are many things that can cause the page to load something other than explicit user actions. Some sites may auto-refresh on a timer (slashdot used to do this). Some sites may use ajax or websockets to check for new content on the server (stackexchange does this). The traffic generated by such scripts is likely to be visible to anyone monitoring your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you are viewing is not reloaded, then the requests never get sent again, until you reload it.

Here are options to mitigate this too.

1. Use a VPN. This will keep all of your data secured from inspections.
2. Use airplane mode, or don't turn on Wi-Fi, our use cellular, if you are viewing something your work would disapprove of.
3. Use an app like *Evernote* to store a copy and view the copy using the app on your phone.